# Linq EF - How to gather all the accounts, cards, loans etc of a specific customer from database, with an optimized query?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq

I'm trying to gather all the information of a specific customer from my database, but i'm not sure how to gather all the information in an optimized query, without querying the database several times.

I've got the following tables: https://i.stack.imgur.com/QHJUJ.png

What I want is to match 1 customer with the provided CustomerId. Then gather all the cards, accounts, loans and permenentorders related to that account.

I've managed to do it but using several queries to my _context. I want to learn how to do optimized queries when joining multiple tables.

Could someone more experienced with Linq provide an example of a query to gather all the cards, accounts, loans and permenentorders related to a customer with the CustomerId of "1"?

I would be very grateful to get some tips and help with this, knowing how to do optimized queries is a very essential skill to have. Thanks a lot! :-)

Example of what i've tried myself:

```
model.Customer = await _context.Customers.SingleOrDefaultAsync(c => c.CustomerId == request.CustomerId);

        model.Accounts = await (from acc in _context.Accounts
                                join disp in _context.Dispositions on acc.AccountId equals disp.AccountId
                                where disp.CustomerId == request.CustomerId
                                select acc).ToListAsync();

        model.Cards = await (from card in _context.Cards
                             join disp in _context.Dispositions on card.DispositionId equals disp.DispositionId
                             where disp.CustomerId == request.CustomerId
                             select card).ToListAsync();
```

Here's my viewmodel that i'm trying to fill with data:

```
 public class GetCustomerDetailsViewmodel
{
    public Customer Customer { get; set; }
    public List<Account> Accounts { get; set; } = new List<Account>();
    public decimal TotalBalance { get; set; }
    public List<Card> Cards { get; set; } = new List<Card>();
    public List<PermenentOrder> PermantentOrders { get; set; } = new List<PermenentOrder>();
    public List<Loan> Loans { get; set; } = new List<Loan>();

}
```

**Customers** have a list of Dispositions, the link table between Customers - Accounts and Cards.

```
**Customers**
PK CustomerId
public virtual ICollection<Disposition> Dispositions { get; set; }

 **Cards**:
PK public int CardId { get; set; }
FK public int DispositionId { get; set; }
public virtual Disposition Disposition { get; set; }

**Dispositions**:
PK public int DispositionId { get; set; }
FK public int CustomerId { get; set; }
   public int AccountId { get; set; }
public virtual Account Account { get; set; }
public virtual Customer Customer { get; set; }
public virtual ICollection<Card> Cards { get; set; }

**Accounts**:
PK public int AccountId { get; set; }
public virtual ICollection<Disposition> Dispositions { get; set; }
public virtual ICollection<Loan> Loans { get; set; }
public virtual ICollection<PermenentOrder> PermenentOrder { get; set; }
public virtual ICollection<Transaction> Transactions { get; set; }

**Loans**
PK public int LoanId { get; set; }
public virtual Account Account { get; set; }

**PermenentOrder**
PK public int OrderId { get; set; }
FK public int AccountId { get; set; }
public virtual Account Account { get; set; }
```

Comment: There is `dbSet.Include(...)` even with Expression support if you add `using System.Data.Entity;`

Comment: Add your viewmodel code to the question as code, not image.

Comment: I tried the following:

'var test = await _context.Dispositions
                .Include(d => d.Account)
                .ThenInclude(d => d.Loans)
                .Include(d => d.Account)
                .ThenInclude(d => d.PermenentOrder)
                .Include(d => d.Cards)
                .Where(c => c.CustomerId == request.CustomerId)
                .Distinct()
                .FirstOrDefaultAsync();'

Unfortunately i'm not sure how to get multiple accounts, as i'm only getting one account with my query. Any insight? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplest query will be to query separately instead of cramming into single linq statement as the statement grows, linq becomes more and more inefficient.

**With Lazy loading,**

You can do something simple like,

```
var model = new GetCustomerDetailsViewmodel();
model.Customer = context.Customers.SingleOrDefault(c => c.CustomerId == id);
if (model.Customer != null)
{
     model.Accounts = model.Customer.Dispositions.Select(x => x.Account).ToList();
     model.Cards = model.Customer.Dispositions.SelectMany(x => x.Cards).ToList();
     model.PermantentOrders = model.Accounts.SelectMany(x => x.PermenentOrder).ToList();
}
```

**Without Lazy Loading,**

You need to load everything in the single query, Beware this might not be the efficient query. Linq is never about efficiency, but convenience and ease of writing.

```
var customerProfile = context.Customers.Where(x => x.CustomerId == id).Select(x => new
        {
            Customer = x,
            Accounts = x.Dispositions.Select(d => d.Account),
            Cards = x.Dispositions.SelectMany(d => d.Cards).ToList(),
            PermanentOrders = x.Dispositions.SelectMany(d => d.Account.PermenentOrder),
        }).FirstOrDefault();

        if (customerProfile != null)
        {
            var model = new GetCustomerDetailsViewmodel();
            model.Customer = customerProfile.Customer;
            model.Accounts = customerProfile.Accounts.ToList();
            model.Cards = customerProfile.Cards.ToList();
            model.PermantentOrders = customerProfile.PermanentOrders.ToList();
        }
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply Mat! I tried out your code but it did not load the accounts, cards or permenentorders. Only the Customer was loaded. https://i.imgur.com/aaIeWtm.png

Do you know why? I really liked your approach since it was very short and straight forward. Perhaps it's got something to do with lazy/eager loading? Thanks

Comment: Is the [lazy loading](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/querying/related-data#lazy-loading) enabled?

Comment: Hi Mat, lazy loading is not enabled. My teacher warned me not to enable it to avoid loading unnecessary data. What do you suggest doing?

Comment: You should enable lazy loading, but should not expose entity types directly in the view models properties. Lazy loading does not load unnecessary data, it by design loads only necessary data. Use a customer view model with necessary properties, then change customer property to that model class. That way, accidental loading of unnecessary data can be avoided.

Answer (score 2):

I think you can use this:

```
model.Customer = await _context.Customers
    .Include(x => x.Dispositions)
    .ThenInclude(x => x.Cards)
    // and other Entities you need, use Include or if entities are in Accounts
    // or Cards can use ThenInclude
    .SingleOrDefaultAsync(c => c.CustomerId == request.CustomerId);
```

Comment: Customers have a collection of Dispositions, they unfortunately don't have a list of Cards. Dispositions is the link table between them. Any suggestions? I haven't used include before, i'm trying to read up on it right now :-)
Edit: I edited my post and added that info

Comment: I think you can use `Include` and `ThenInclude` but put models in your question then I can help better to you.

Comment: I've updated my post, tell me if i missed anything that you'd like to know :-) Thanks for your replies

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/mbLV9p8.png :
`model.Customer = await _context.Customers
                    .Include(x => x.Dispositions)
                    .ThenInclude(x => x.Cards)
                    .Include(c => c.Dispositions)
                    .ThenInclude(c => c.Account)
                    .ThenInclude(c => c.Loans)
                    .Include(c => c.Dispositions)
                    .ThenInclude(c => c.Account)
                    .ThenInclude(c => c.PermenentOrder)
                    .SingleOrDefaultAsync(c => c.CustomerId == request.CustomerId);`
It worked! Thanks a bunch!!

Comment: for further optimization, you can select only the data you need with the query instead of returning everything. i.e: `.Select(x => new ViewModel{ Blah = x.Blah, Children = x.Blah.Children }` instead of returning the entire entities as is happening now with `.SingleOrDefault`. With large tables that have a lot of columns, this will make a pretty big difference. This is essentially the diff in sql between `select * from table` and `select col1, col2 from table`

Comment: the cleanest way to handle this situation is this answer and it can be accepted as right answer but if you insist on not using include and thenInclude in your code you can use join between your entities

Comment: Would you mind giving me an example on how i could use .Select instead? I've tried the following: https://i.imgur.com/NwOKMSH.png (Can't post entire query in comment, too many characters). Thanks

Comment: you should cast every select to viewmodel like this: `select new ParentViewModel
{
   Id = p.Id,
   Children = p.Children.Select(c => new ChildViewModel {
       Id = c.Id,
       Toys = c.Toys.Select(t => new ToyViewModel { ... }).ToList()
   }).ToList()
};`